# How to use custom html element in admin form field?

Tags: adminform, renderer

```
$fieldset->addField('rating', 'label', array(
        'name'      => 'rating',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('sellerreview')->__('Rating'),
        'title'     => Mage::helper('sellerreview')->__('Rating'),
        'renderer'  => 'sellerreview/adminhtml_review_renderer_image',

    ));
```

this is my image.php file

```
 public function render(Varien_Object $row) {

    $fullRating = $row->getRating();
    $html = '';

        $html = $html.'<input id="input-21d" name="rating" value='. $fullRating .' type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.5 data-size="sm" data-disabled="true">';


    return $html;
}
```

Is this right method to use renderer in addfield form? How to use renderer in addfield form

Comment: are you taking about admin form fields

Comment: yes admin form field

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**Renderer file:**

```
class NameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Renderer_Images extends  Varien_Data_Form_Element_Abstract
{
    
    public function getElementHtml()
    {   
    
        $html = '';         
            $html = $html.'<input id="input-21d" name="rating" value="2" type="number" class="rating" min=0 max=5 step=0.5 data-size="sm" data-disabled="true">';           
        return $html;
    }
}
```

in your **form.php**

```
$fieldset->addType('customtype', '[NameSpace]_[ModuleName]_Block_Adminhtml_Review_Renderer_Images');     
     $fieldset->addField('rating', 'customtype', array(
        'name'      => 'rating',
        'label'     => Mage::helper('[modulename]')->__('Rating'),
    ));
```

using this you can use **custom html** in admin form field

Comment: It should called custom html element. not called renderer in basic magento

Comment: @ND17 In this example, renderer file name should be Images.php, right ?

Comment: @SagarPPanchal Yes

Comment: To get the value of the element, use `$this->getValue()`.

Answer (score 2):

you are almost correct here i suggest you about my working example to display image of field in grid

**Grid.php**

```
$this->addColumn('after_image', array(
          'header'    => Mage::helper('testimonials')->__('After Image'),
          'align'     =>'left',
          'index'     => 'after_image',
          'renderer'  => 'testimonials/adminhtml_testimonials_edit_renderer_testimonialafimage',
      ));
```

where `testimonials` is your block tag in config.xml

and your render file should be like as define in your renderer index

```
<?php
class Yournamespace_Testimonials_Block_Adminhtml_Testimonials_Edit_Renderer_Testimonialafimage extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract
  {
     public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {       

        if($row->getId()) {             
         $imageName = $row->getAfterImage();                
        $imagePath = Mage::getBaseUrl("media").$imageName; 
        $dirImg = Mage::getBaseDir().str_replace("/",DS,strstr($imagePath,'/media'));        

        if (file_exists($dirImg) && !empty($imageName)) {           
            return  "<img width='50px' height='50px' src='".Mage::getBaseUrl("media").$imageName."' />"; 
        }else{
             return  "<img width='50px' height='50px' src='".Mage::getBaseUrl("media").'testimonial/not-available.jpg'."' />"; 
        }          
        }
    }  
}     
 ?>
```

**EDIT**

Use renderer in Edit form you can see rating edit form of admin

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Rating_Edit_Tab_Form

 $field = $fieldset->addField('stores', 'multiselect', array(
            'label' => Mage::helper('rating')->__('Visible In'),
            'name' => 'stores[]',
            'values' => Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/system_store')->getStoreValuesForForm()
        ));
        $renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('adminhtml/store_switcher_form_renderer_fieldset_element');
        $field->setRenderer($renderer);
```

hope this will be enough to get idea.

Comment: I want to display in admin edit form not in grid

Comment: @ND17, see my updated answer

Comment: not working....

Comment: it should work, check your block path ' adminhtml' is for default magento's change with your block and renderer path

Comment: is this correct? $renderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('sellerreview/adminhtml_review_renderer_image');
        $field->setRenderer($renderer);

Comment: using this i can't pass value of rating in image.php so how to pass value

Comment: it seems you can get in render function  `public function render(Varien_Object $row)
    {  
    
   if($row->getId())        {} entire row value

Comment: for example see this class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Report_Grid_Column_Renderer_Currency`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22729/discussion-between-nd17-and-liyakat).

Comment: if my answer is helpful to you please don't forget to acpt it. so someone can use in future

Comment: you are talking about grid.php but OP is referring to form.php.